# Netlify dont deploy specific folder or files

Tags: netlify

I have a git a repository set up with CD on Netlify. The site itself is 4 files, but I have some other files I'd like to add to the repository that I don't want deployed. Is there a way to deploy only certain files with a deployment? Or only a specific folder?

My site only requires an http server, there's not an npm, jekyll, or hugo install. It's just the deployment of 4 files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put the files in a specific folder you can set the Base Directory in your Build & Deploy settings to that directory and it will ignore the other files/folders not in that directory.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/ignore-builds/#mimic-default-behavior), this is a bit more involved than just setting the base repo:

---

For this next example, consider a monorepo project set up like this, where blog-1 is the base directory.

```
repository-root/
├─ package.json
└─ workspaces/
   ├─ blog-1/
   │  ├─ package.json
   │  └─ netlify.toml
   ├─ common/
   │  └─ package.json
   └─ blog-2/
      ├─ package.json
      └─ netlify.toml
```

The following ignore command example adapts the default behavior so that the build proceeds only if there are changes within the blog-1 or common directories.

```
[build]
  ignore = "git diff --quiet $CACHED_COMMIT_REF $COMMIT_REF . ../common/"
```